# Removing items from cart ajax

Tags: woocommerce

On the site, the cart is displayed in a modal window through a shortcode.
The problem - when you delete one product - all are deleted at once.
It is necessary that each item is deleted correctly..

php upd:

```
function warp_ajax_product_remove()
{
ob_start();

foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item)
{
if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] && $cart_item_key == $_POST['cart_item_key'] )
{
WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
}
}

WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();

// Fragments and mini cart are returned
$data = array(
'fragments' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', array(
'div.widget_shopping_cart_content' => '<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">' . $mini_cart . '</div>'
)
),
'cart_hash' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_hash', WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ? md5( json_encode(
WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() ) ) : '', WC()->cart->get_cart_for_session() )
);

wp_send_json( $data );

die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_remove', 'warp_ajax_product_remove' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'warp_ajax_product_remove' );
```

JS file upd

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.remove', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var product_id = $(this).attr("data-product_id"),
          cart_item_key = $(this).attr("data-cart_item_key"),
          product_container = $(this).parents('.cart_item');
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
          data: {
             action: "product_remove",
             product_id: product_id,
             cart_item_key: cart_item_key
          },
          success: function (response) {
             if (!response || response.error) return;
             var fragments = response.fragments;
    
             // Replace fragments
             if (fragments) {
                $.each(fragments, function (key, value) {
                   $(key).replaceWith(value);
                });
             }
             product_container.remove();
             
          }
       });
    });
```

I got the removal. Now, when deleting, the final price does not change. How can I do that? Updated the code above.

Comment: can you share a site link? are you sure it's deleted all items? because as you wrote this line `$( '.popup-cart' ).html(data);` which is override whatever you sending from ajax side and in your case you are not sending anything so `'.popup-cart'` will empty.

Comment: https://ca30587.tmweb.ru/
top click on the basket and delete the product

Comment: ajax not working at all.

Comment: I got the removal. Now, when deleting, the final price does not change. How can I do that? Updated the code above. code upd.